# Laravel: How to add a relation instead of field to `->withPivot()`

Tags: laravel

I know how to add another field to a pivot table

```
public function scheduledPrograms()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('ScheduledProgram', 'prog_bookings')->withPivot('paid','registered');
}
```

but how would I add a relation so for example if `registered` were another table with a `hasOne` relation that I could use to show the `order_number` and `status` and other fields, etc.

Comment: The pivot tables should be used when you're working with many to many relationships so it shouldn't have a `hasOne` relation in the model.

Comment: Laravel doesn't support relations on pivot tables so the best you can do is create an additional model for the pivot table and use that.